# How to create dependencies in statechart?

Tags: uml, statechart

[Example StateChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WFXv.png)

I've got a system, that is depending on another system. 
I want to display this in a statechart.

System 1: **microwave_state** with two states: **On** and **Off**

When microwave_button is pressed AND system 2 current state is true, then ON
else Off

System 2: **electricity_state** with two states: **True** and **False**.
When electricity bill is payed then True else False

How can I display that dependency in a statachart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it like this:

[image]

The "current from system2" is just a guard for the transition. From my POV `system2` is not a state machine, but a simple boolean value.

Comment: I've added an alternative statechart above in my post - is that right, too?

Comment: That would be ok, though it's more an activity diagram since "checking current" is not really a state but a momentary/transient check.